# unknown command using screen -X

Tags: bash, gnu-screen

I have a screen called railsServer. I want to start rails in it.

```
screen -S railsServer -p 0 -X "rails s"
```

However in the other terminal window that I try running this command in, this comes up.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iduBF.png)

```
-X: unknown command 'rails s'
```

Comment: Bezzoon, this question may be more successful in [superuser.com](http://superuser.com/), since it's a terminal related question.

Answer (score 1):

Ohh...

```
screen -S railsServer -p 0 -X stuff "rails s"
```

Is what I wanted.

Granted I am not sure how to run it! The command just pops up in the other screen.

Comment: Use `stuff $'rails s\n'` to stuff a literal newline too.

Comment: Ahh you are correct! I used double quotes and that didn't work! Thanks!

Comment: Is it possible to do something like screen -S railsServer -p 0 -X stuff $'^C' ??

Comment: Yeah, the ANSI C quoting `$'...'` is important there. That seems to work for me (just commented that on your other question too).

Comment: Apparently screen -S railsServer -p 0 -X stuff $'\003' is what I was looking for !

Comment: All of `\cc`, `^C` and `\003` look like they should work for me. `printf %s $'\cc' $'<ctrl-v><ctrl-c>' $'\003' | xxd -g 1`